# How to combine rows and put into single row in dataframe by sql or python

Tags: python, sql, hiveql

I'd like to aggregate rows in certain column base on the relationship with other column and create certain column which contain aggregated data in json format.

This is the example.

Original data table

```
Child Name     Child Age    Father Name    Father Age
     Peter             5        Richard            40
     James            15           Doug            45
       Liz             2           Doug            45
      Paul             6        Richard            40
    Shirly            11        Charles            33
       Eva             9          Chris            29
```

Converted Data table will be either

```
Father Name    Father Age     Children 
    Richard            40     {"Peter":"5", "Paul":"6"}
       Doug            45     {"James":"15","Liz":"2"}
    Charles            33     {"Shirly" : "11"}
      Chris            29     {"Eva" : "9"}
```

Or

```
Father Name    Father Age     Children Name       Children Age
    Richard            40     {"Peter", "Paul"}      {"5","6"}
       Doug            45     {"James", "Liz"}      {"15","2"}
    Charles            33     {"Shirly"}                {"11"}
      Chris            29     {"Eva"}                    {"9"}
```

My code is

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Child Name" : ["Peter","James","Liz","Paul","Shirly","Eva"],
    "Child Age" : ["5","15","2","6","11","9"],
    "Father Name" : ["Richard","Doug","Doug","Richard","Charles","Chris"],
    "Father Age" : ["40","45","45","40","33","29"] })

 print df

g1 = df.groupby(["Father Name"])["Child Name"].apply(", ".join).reset_index()
g1.columns = ['Father Name','Children Name']
print g1
```

and the output will be

```
  Father Name   Children Name
0     Charles          Shirly
1       Chris             Eva
2        Doug      James, Liz
3     Richard     Peter, Paul
```

I can't figure out how to add "Father Age" and "Children Age" in the columns.
how can I convert this in dataframe in most efficient way?
I'd like to avoid loop via python as it will take long to process.

thanks,

Comment: Your original table is not normalized. You should have a separate father table and child table.

Comment: I don't get it about normalization on original table. can you elaborate it more detail with simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick dirty inefficient hack, but it avoids for loops. Would love to have a better solution; I assume the multiple df copies and multiple merges could be simplified.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Child Name" : ["Peter","James","Liz","Paul","Shirly","Eva"],
    "Child Age" : ["5","15","2","6","11","9"],
    "Father Name" : ["Richard","Doug","Doug","Richard","Charles","Chris"],
    "Father Age" : ["40","45","45","40","33","29"] })

g2 = df.groupby(['Father Name'])["Child Name"].apply(list).reset_index()
g3 = df.groupby(['Father Name'])["Child Age"].apply(list).reset_index()
g4 = df[["Father Name", "Father Age"]].drop_duplicates()

df2 = g2.merge(g4)
df2 = df2.merge(g3)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  Father Name     Child Name Father Age Child Age
0     Charles       [Shirly]         33      [11]
1       Chris          [Eva]         29       [9]
2        Doug   [James, Liz]         45   [15, 2]
3     Richard  [Peter, Paul]         40    [5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks Evan for your time, this is close to the output I want although it doesn't create data either json or list format.

Comment: Ah, got it. There's an easy enough change to get a list - see revised code :)